# Display of profile page

Tags: bug, status-declined

First off, I don't know where we are supposed to report problems with site, so I am putting it here. Two quick items:

On the old site, I thought there was a link to your profile. Where did the link go, or am I just missing it?

When I open my profile page, I see a lot of blank space and my profile is pushed to the left. I have to use the scroll bar to move all the way to the left to read my profile. This is happening with IE7 at work, haven't tried at home or with different browsers.

Trying to do screen shot here - there we go!
[image: Screen shot]

Updated screen shot from Stack Overflow
[image: Stack Overflow Screen Shot]

Comment: This is the correct place to ask a question like this. However, I'm not sure I understand your trouble. Can you provide some screenshots of the weird profile page appearance?

Comment: My profile page, like every page on this site, is extremely wide. The horizontal scroll bar elevator is this big: [[]] When the page loads, the "Ask Question" toolbar button is centered on the page, and I have to scroll to the left to see my whole profile.

Comment: Per @Jin, the [new design doesn't support IE7](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/422/missing-centre-right-section-of-header). Maybe he can see if it is an easy fix or not. Thankfully I was able to get FF and IE8 before the new design was rolled out. x_x

Comment: That explains it - the "Login Meta Chat FAQ" menu items next to search are not shown in IE7. They do show in Firefox and IE6, and the profile page looks normal. So why does it work in IE6 but not IE7? Weird.

Comment: The answer to that question is IE7 ;)

Comment: So, if Stack Overflow can show my links in IE7, why can't this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an IE7 issue. We have not supported IE7 in a good while. I've thought about making an exception for this site since there are more Microsoft product users than our other SE sites. But even then, IE7 % is so low that I can't justify it.

Comment: Well, I am stuck with the one browser my customer allows, except on a test machine. The funny thing is, the site looks fine on IE6. I'm curious as to what exactly in the CSS/HTML is causing this to happen only for IE7.

Comment: And... my comment didn't save. I am now left-aligned, so I can see my profile without scrolling, so i can live with that. But, as I show in the second screen shot above, Stack Overflow can show my links in IE7. Why can't we show them in this site?